# Implement generic interface with generic type in Java

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to implement a generic interface in Java with a generic type and am getting compilation errors. I am wondering if the following is possible:

```
public class ListResponse<T> {
    private List<T> response;

    public ListResponse(List<T> response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    public List<T> getResponse() {
        return response;
    }
}
```

And the troublesome class:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.List;
import com.myorg.response.ListResponse;

public class ListPresenter<T> implements Consumer<ListResponse<T>> {
    private ListResponse<T> response;

    public <T> void accept(ListResponse<T> response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    // Rest of class
}
```

I was hoping to then have calling code like this:

```
ListPresenter<Integer> presenter = new ListPresenter<>();
```

However I get a compilation error with the following message:

```
 error: ListPresenter is not abstract and does not override abstract
 method accept(ListResponse<T>) in Consumer [ERROR] where T is a
 type-variable: [ERROR] T extends Object declared in class
 ListPresenter
```

Comment: `public <T> void accept(ListResponse<T> response)` should be `public void accept(ListResponse<T> response)` (first `<T>` removed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are re-defining the generic parameter `<T>` on method `accept(...)`. The mechanic is similar to hiding attributes through local variables with the same name.

The `T` on `public <T> void accept(ListResponse<T> response)` is not "coupled" to the `T` on `public class ListPresenter<T> implements Consumer<ListResponse<T>>`.

The issue can be fixed by removing the first `<T>` on the declaration of method `accept(...)`:

```
public class ListPresenter<T> implements Consumer<ListResponse<T>> {
    ...
    public void accept(ListResponse<T> response) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In ListPresenter Class you are Not Implementing the Consumer's accept method properly

We use generics to allow Types(Integer,Float etc) to be the parameter.
When we define a class or something to use Generics we Use these Angular Brackets 
 but when we have to use this type we don't have to use Angular Brackets

Example :-

```
interface Consumer<T> { //Defining Interface that's why using <>

    void accept(T t); //here this method can accept a parameter of T type

    T returnSomething(int n) //here this method is having return type of T
}
```

So in your ListPresenter class you are giving two types of return type to the accept method of Consumer interface.

```
public <T> void accept(ListResponse<T> response)
```

should be this

```
public void accept(ListResponse<T> response)
```

or This if it have a generic return type

```
public T accept(ListResponse<T> response)
```